# Regular expression pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create pattern for following string

1. `abc deff <XYZ>.xls`
2. `<XYZ> abc.xlsx`
3. `ABCD.csv`

by using below pattern

```html
(\\w*)(\\<)(\\w*)(\\>)(\\w*)(\\.)(\\w*)
```

but it is not working for me

expected output

```html
1. abc deff <XYZ>.xls
   g1 = abc deff 
   g2 = XYZ
   g3 = xls
   
2. <XYZ> abc.xlxs
   g1 = "" 
   g2 = XYZ
   g3 = xlxs
   
3. ABCD.csv
   g1 = ABCD 
   g2 = ""
   g3 = csv
```

Comment: If you're trying to match files, you're probably better of with a `PathMatcher`, either using regex or glob, instead of a whole pattern.

Comment: How come your 3rd match contains a `csv` in Group 3 if the string had no `csv` in it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably usage of `?` and `(?=...(...))` syntax will help you. Try something like this:

```
([^\\.<]*)(<[^>]+>)?(?=\\.(.*))
```

For a phrase `abc deff <XYZ>.xls` it gives three groups `abc deff`, `<XYZ>` and `xls`. With usage of positive look-ahead you should be able to avoid `<>` in the match if needed, see how it is done for `xls`-matching group.